# Solving equations with mod in Sage

Tags: modular-arithmetic, sagemath

I'm trying to use Sage to solve equations, but can't seem to get a toy example running.

Lets say I want to solve for `x`, where `x=(1/17) mod 780`, the answer should be `413`.

I define a variable in Sage as:

`sage: var('x')`

Then I try to solve using:

`sage: func=(x==(1/17)%780)`

`sage: solve(func)`

However it just returns the message `IndexError: tuple index out of range`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I believe the double equals `==` is the right syntax for the "equals" in an equation for Sage.

Comment: Yep, this is just an example, I,'m more wondering about solving more complex functions with mod..

Comment: That's really cool thanks @Moo, that worked, I guess I just thought I could include 'mod' as a standard function parameter

Comment: If you wanna write that as an answer I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use solve mod, like $\text{solve_mod(x==(1/17),780)}$

You can run this in the online https://cocalc.com/ or with https://sagecell.sagemath.org/

You can see more examples at; https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/calculus/sage/symbolic/relation.html

Comment: Thanks again...